# Can't centre header logo - wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

I've tried a number of things including using the centre text tag (in CSS) and the yellow pencil plugin to try and centre the logo on this website:

[The website](http://twinklewinkle.co.uk/newsite/wordpress/)

Via yellow pencil I can get it centred on desktop and ipad, but when it goes down to a smart phone device the logo disappears. What is the best way to centre this logo?

J

*edit*

I have tried applying this CSS to the logo:

```
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

Comment: Please post your code. Remember to follow the guidelines of a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Do you need to center it this way? https://www.screencast.com/t/LUSwPS4g1Pn

Comment: Further to @disinfor's comment, please read this [Something on my website doesn't work, can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: @AlexZahorodnyk, yes, that's the one.

Comment: Ah Chaps, notice how I said I'm using the yellow pencil plugin?

Comment: Notice how you're meant to be able to replicate a problem in order for us to work on it?

Comment: Not really interested in a fight Pete. If Alex wants to work with me, cool.

Comment: The problem is you're using tables in a bizarre way. I'd suggest writing your html/css the way you want to use it. At the moment you have the logo in one table cell and the nav in a second, then slid down. You'd be better off using the block elements like they're meant to display or using a table and putting your logo and nav elements on seperate rows.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make changes for the following CSS selectors:

```
#header_wrap #header_border #header #header_container {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}

#header_wrap #header_border #header #header_container #logo {
    display: block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}

#header_wrap #header_border #header #header_container #logo a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    float: none;
}

#header_wrap #header_border #header #header_container #menu_wrap {
    display: block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    top: -20px;
}

#menu_wrap #menu_container > div > ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

ul#menu-main-menu {
    width: 684px;
    left: 0px;
    position: static;
}
```

Should work for you. See [screenshot](https://www.screencast.com/t/3xS10Kck).
Let me know if it doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you can't centre the logo is because the menu div with the ID "menu-wrap" takes up a huge blank space above it, so you can't move the logo into this space. You need to style the menu differently.